# How would you get the epoch time and convert it to local time in arm assembly on a raspberry pi?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

So I am programming in arm assembly on raspbian and I am trying to convert the epoch time using c/c++ libraries because that is what I am allowed to do, but I am confused as to how to do it. If I simply `bl time` it will give me the epoch time, but I am confused as to how I would get the return value in r0, then convert that into the local time in assembly using C or C++ libraries. I know localtime/gmtime and strftime exist, but its not as easy as getting the epoch and just `bl localtime` or `bl strftime`. Then I want to format it where I only get the local time and maybe am/pm. I am not interested in the date. I just need some helpful code, or some direction to be pushed into. Thanks

Edit: If its easier to just convert using math that would also be helpful

Comment: well you need to know when the epoch is usually, and the units of the return value.  is it in seconds since the epoch?  if all you care about is the time and not the date, then get the remainder of the division of how many units of ticks per day.  if seconds then divide by the number of seconds per day, if the epoch starts at midnight then the result is the number of ticks, lets assumes seconds in that day, if that is less than 12 hours worth of seconds it is am if more than 12 hours worth it is pm.  Its not a language nor library thing, just math.

Comment: If you want date then that is a WHOLE lot more fun, gotta deal with ticks per year, leap years, months not having the same number of days, etc.  can look at open source implementations of the time functions for shortcuts, or just do it brute force.

Comment: and for local time then add time zones to it, hours adjusted from gmt for your location and time of year.

Comment: Do a couple of divisions and modulo division and you will get time in 24 he format, then get am or pm with value of (hour/12) and exact time with (hour%12)

Comment: Ok so its in seconds, but I believe it uses military time, so all I would have to is the epoch time/86400 and whatever the remainder of that is the number of seconds that is currently in the day, which I could pin point what hour and minute that is? @old_timer

Comment: What exactly would I be dividing though? If I divide epoch by number of seconds in the day I would get number of days no? And what value would the remainder represent btw @PunyCode

Comment: explain how it uses military time, it is number of seconds since the epoch, thats it seconds since the epoch there is no hours minutes, am/pm, days weeks.  just seconds.  you turn seconds into whatever you want, hours minutes military or am/pm, whatever time zone, etc...

Comment: that is what a remainder means right?  you need to adjust for time zone first though.

Comment: Ah. So if I divide my the number of seconds in a day I would get the number of days, then if I multiplied that by 24 I would get the number of hours since then. If I wanted to find the remaining amount of hours in the year would I just take the remainder of hours since epoch and 365? or would I have to convert the hours/days into years since epoch and take the remainder of time till 2020 which would be 50 years? @old_timer

Comment: years and months are more complicated, you have leap years so you have to work your way through those, and then months dont have the same number of days so you have to work through those.

Comment: and then there are leap seconds, I wonder if any os/library cares about those.  for now you wanted am/pm time today.  so you have to first adjust for timezone, then divide by 24 hours (worth of seconds) and save the remainder, the remainder is then the number of seconds today, then you can turn that into hours/minutes/seconds.  which if you are struggling with the 24 hour a day thing then hours/minutes/seconds is even more work.  as you are keeping the result and the remainder of the divisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to not do your homework for you, here is an example.  All of this is basic grade school math, no magic.

If I have 345678 pennies how does that brake down into various dollar and coin amounts.

There are 100 pennies in a dollar and 100 dollars in a 100 dollar bill, so

345678 / (100*100) = 34 remainder 5678

Looking at units

pennies / (pennies/dollar * dollars/hundred) =

(pennies * dollars * hundreds) / (pennies * dollars )

pennies and dollars cancel out left with hundreds which is correct

so 34 hundred dollar bills with a remainder of 5678 pennies

repeat for 20 dollar bills

5678 / (100 * 20) = 2 remainder 1678

10 dollar bills

1678 / (100 * 10) = 1 remainder 678

5 dollar bills

678 / (100 * 5) = 1 remainder 178

one dollar bills

178 / (100 * 1) = 1 remainder 78

50 cent pieces

78 / 50 = 1 remainder 28

quarters (25 cents)

28 / 25 = 1 remainder 3

dimes (10 cents) 0 remainder 3

nickles (5 cents) 0 remainder 3

pennies the remainder 3

so 345678 pennies is equal to

```
34 100 dollar bills +
 2  20 dollar bills +
 1  10 dollar bill +
 1  5 dollar bill +
 1  1 dollar bill +
 1  half dollar coin +
 1  quarter +
 3  pennies
```

check the work

```
34 * 100 * 100 = 340000 
2  * 100 * 20  = 4000
1  * 100 * 10  = 1000
1  * 100 * 5   = 500
1 * 100        = 100
1 * 50         = 50
1 * 25         = 25
1 * 3          = 3
add that up you get 345678
```

If I simply wanted to know how many quarters

345678 / (25 * 1) = 13827 quarters with a remainder of 3.

it all works the same with 60 seconds per minute 60 minutes per hour 24 hours per day. 365 days for 1970, 365 days for 1971, 366 days for 1972 365 days for 1973 and so on

31 days for january, 28 days for february 2019, 31 days for march and so on

easier to adjust for timezone first  60 seconds * 60 minutes * hours of adjustment
add or subtract that off as needed, then work that number either through the years/months/days or if you simply care about time of day then you only need to divide by seconds per day.  or you can divide by seconds per day and get total days as a result with fraction of a day as a remainder, the fraction of a day is the time of day today and the total days you can then later subtract off the years then months to find the date.

Extra credit, what year will computers with 32 bit time counters using the 1970 epoch have a Y2K like roll over event (causing crashes and death and destruction across the planet just like Y2K)?

The programming language is irrelevant until the algorithm is understood and ideally coded in a favorite high level language, to confirm/prove the algorithm.  Then port that knowledge to some other programming language.

Shortcutting the steps will sometimes get you there faster but when the shortcut fails it fails in spectacular fashion.

Comment: Wow old timer thank you for making realize something that I KNEW was so obvious, but since I haven't visited in such a long time completely forgot. As of me righting this the current epoch time is  1576189924 % 86400 and take the remainder of that I get 81124 seconds left. If I divide that by (60 *60) (60 seconds in a minute x 60 minutes in an hour)  I get 22 hours and 1924 seconds. Now finally if I divide that by 60  32 minutes. Which in the GMT time which this is from is 22:32:40 seconds. Thanks!